# Error while uninstalling a gem

Tags: rubygems, rvm

I'm trying a to uninstall a gem from this gemsest :

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
my_gem_to_delete (0.0.1) <-- this one
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
```

So :

```
gem uninstall my_gem_to_delete
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    my_gem_to_delete is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /home/my_name//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@my_gem_to_delete my_gem_to_delete
```

The last command produce this error.

Have I missed something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove the gem file from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247...

*you may need to search for it to find the real path, since you've obscured it from us*

Comment: just a rm of the directory will be ok? But any idea why the gem command is failing?

Comment: not the entire directory, just the directory for that specific gem.  My guess is that you've already tried to uninstall it, but something went wrong and RVMs directory structure is now out of sync.  One of several reasons I now use `rbenv` instead.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you did change gemsets, run:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247@my_gem_to_delete
```

and then remove the gem